# UNIX grep command syntax for lines containing at least 35 characters

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to print only the lines that contain, let say, at least 35 characters, from a file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Close voters: The question appears to be about shell scripting, which is a subset of programming, and therefore on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is not the best tool for this job.

You could write:

```
grep ................................... filename
```

or use one of the more sophisticated regular expression features mentioned in other answers (if your `grep` supports them). But `awk`:

```
awk 'length >= 35' filename
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print if length >= 35' filename
```

would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

grep with `-P` (Perl regular expression) or `-E` (extended regular expression) switch OR `egrep` should work:

```
grep -E '.{35,}' file
```

OR

```
grep -P '.{35,}' file
```

OR using egrep:

```
egrep '.{35,}' file
```

Comment: I thought it was `grep -e` for regex

Comment: @Cratylus: Actually both `-E` OR `-P` should work but `-e` won't.

Comment: `grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep`; `grep -P` is supported in recent GNU `grep`, but isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `$ grep -E '^.{35,}$'` the extended version of `grep`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regular expressions :

```
grep -E ".{35,}" file
```

or

```
cat file | grep -E ".{35,}"
```

The dot means a character (letter, digit), and the {35,} means at least 35 character or more.

**man grep** if you want more informations

Comment: Now better prepare for a useless-use-of-cat award!